# Splitting a Dataset into Uneven Portions

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have this data set:

```
var_1 = rnorm(1027,1000,1000)
var_2 = rnorm(1027,1000,1000)
var_3 = rnorm(1027,1000,1000)

sample_data = data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3)
```

I want to split this data into sections of 100:

```
list_of_dfs <- split(
  sample_data, (seq(nrow(sample_data))-1) %/% 100
)
```

However, since the number of rows in this data set is not cleanly divisible by 100 - I get 10 sections instead of 11 sections (i.e. 10 full sections and 1 non-full section):

```
summary(list_of_dfs)
   Length Class      Mode
0  3      data.frame list
1  3      data.frame list
2  3      data.frame list
3  3      data.frame list
4  3      data.frame list
5  3      data.frame list
6  3      data.frame list
7  3      data.frame list
8  3      data.frame list
9  3      data.frame list
10 3      data.frame list
```

- Is it possible to adjust the R code so that 11 sections are created instead of 10 sections?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grp_size <- 100
n <- nrow(sample_data)
split(sample_data, gl(ceiling(n/grp_size), grp_size, length = n))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
var_1 = rnorm(1027,1000,1000)
var_2 = rnorm(1027,1000,1000)
var_3 = rnorm(1027,1000,1000)

sample_data = data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3)

sample_data <- sample_data %>% 
  mutate(obs = 0:(n()-1), 
         group = floor(obs/100) + 1)

list_of_dfs <- split(
  sample_data, 
  sample_data$group
)


summary(list_of_dfs)
#>    Length Class      Mode
#> 1  5      data.frame list
#> 2  5      data.frame list
#> 3  5      data.frame list
#> 4  5      data.frame list
#> 5  5      data.frame list
#> 6  5      data.frame list
#> 7  5      data.frame list
#> 8  5      data.frame list
#> 9  5      data.frame list
#> 10 5      data.frame list
#> 11 5      data.frame list
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>